# regular expression to validate strings having specific characters

Tags: ios, regex

I want to develop one regular expression which validates only strings which have "A,B or C".

ABBCCAABBC - should be validated
ABBC - should be validated

ABBDF - Should not

I want to use this in one of my iPhone app.

Comment: I find it a bit strange that you want to 'develop' a regular expression but ask it to be written here for you...

Comment: sorry for poor english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To validate strings that only have A, B, C, and non-empty:

`^[ABC]+$`

`[ABC]` is character set containing any of A, B and C characters.

`+` means one or more

`^` means beginning of string

`$` means end of string

If you want to accept empty string, use `*`, which means zero or more, instead of `+`

Answer (score 1):

once check this one,

```
    NSString *stringToBeTested = @"ABCAAAAAAAAA";

    NSString *RGExpression = @"[A-C]{1,}";
    NSPredicate *evaluate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", RGExpression];

    BOOL matched = [evaluate evaluateWithObject:stringToBeTested];
    NSLog(@"%d",matched);

   string         O/P
---------------------------
@"ABCAAAAAAAAA"       1
@"ASD"                0
@"A"                  1
@""                   0
```

Answer (score 1):

If your scope is really that simple, just use NSCharacterSet create a set of allowed characters, then test membership.